# Adding a birthday to the Google Birthday calendar who isn't a contact

Tags: google-chrome, calendar

Say I want to add my dogs birthday, or my grandson, who's 2, do I have to add my dog as a contact and enter in her birthday.  I don't want to have the Google Birthday calendar and a self made birthday calendar.  When you create an event the Google Birthday calendar is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened Google Calendar on my PC, and then created a new calendar called Birthdays.  I then added the birthdays as all day, repeat yearly events.

Personally, I then renamed Google's Birthday Calendar to something else & changed the color so I could tell the difference, but you don't have to (it was fine with 2 'Birthday' calendars), or you could do it the other way around (e.g. make a 'My Birthdays' calendar and leave Google's Birthday calendar as is).

Answer (score 12):

I about tore my hair out over this same issue, but finally figured out an easy work around for it that can be done in Google Calendar either on a PC or an Android phone.

On Android phone:  Create an event, e.g., "Fido's Birthday."  Then go to that event and tap to open edit.  Under the date and time you will see "Does not repeat."  Tap that. You can change it to repeat annually. Save, and... Voila!

On Google Calendar on a PC, same thing.  Create the birthday as a one day event, then go back in to edit it.  Right under the date and time (upper left) you will see check boxes for either "all day" or "Repeat."  Check "Repeat" and use the drop down menu to select "Yearly." Save, and you're done.

Your dog's birthday is now on your Google Calendar.  :-)

Comment: Nice hack, Repeat: every year.

Comment: Hello it's 2020, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work anymore..

Answer (score 6):

If you want someone to show up on Google's Birthday calendar, they have to be a contact. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/zrmzE_ZlGbY

Comment: Yeah, I found that same page, just wasn't sure if I wasn't finding some hidden menu selection.

Comment: @mrbungle Nope. What you see is what you get. :)